# gridOptions.columnDefs.comparator is not getting called

Tags: angular, ag-grid-ng2

I am using ag grid and I want custom sorting.
I am trying to add custom sort using comparator but it is not getting called on click of column header.

```
gridOptions.columnDefs = [
          {
            headerName: this.localeService.getLocaleText("Status"),
            field: "status",
            width: 100,
            param: this,
            cellRenderer: this.deviceStatusRenderer,
            unSortIcon: true,
            suppressSizeToFit: true
          },
          {
            headerName: this.localeService.getLocaleText("IP/Subnet"),
            field: "ip/Subnet",
            filter: "text",
            width: 250,
            unSortIcon: true,
            comparator : this.ipComparator
          },
          {
            headerName: this.localeService.getLocaleText("systemName"),
            field: "systemName",
            width: 159,
            unSortIcon: true,
          }]
```

and method is

```
ipComparator(){
    console.log('=================');
    return -1;
  }
```

How can I get it called

Comment: I am able to call cellRenderer but comparator is not getting called...